# Relation not being saved with CakePHP hasMany relationship

Tags: cakephp, model

I have two models: `Event` and `Venue`. An Event belongsTo a Venue, and a Venue can have many Events. I'm trying to save both an Event and Venue in one go with a single form. This is what I have so far in my controller:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Event->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Event successfully saved');
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my form:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Event');
    echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
        'legend' => 'Event Details',
        'Event.date',
        'Event.title'
    ));
    echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
        'legend' => 'Venue Details',
        'Venue.name',
        'Venue.street_address',
        'Venue.locality' => array('label' => 'Town/city'),
        'Venue.postal_code'
    ));
    echo $this->Form->end('Save Event');
?>
```

Pretty simple.

Now, both the `Event` and `Venue` records are created. But `venue_id` in my `events` table is zero; it’s not set to the ID of the newly-created Venue. How can I rectify this? I’m sure it’s pretty simple!

**EDIT:** My `Event` model:

```
<?php
class Event extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Event';
    public $actsAs = array(
        'Containable'
    );
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Venue'
    );
}
```

My `Venue` model:

```
<?php
class Venue extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Venue';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Event'
    );
}
```

Comment: Are your associations set up correctly? Looks OK to me

Comment: I believe so. I’ve added my model definitions in the question.

Comment: Cake *suggests* you need to save the primary/parent model first, which at a guess, in this case would be `Venue` `Venue (parent) hasMany Event (children)`. So try doing the same thing but with the `Venue` controller/model/view instead.

Comment: Can you post the content of $this->request->data?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I needed to use `array('deep' => true)` when using the `saveAll()` method.

```
if ($this->Event->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Event successfully saved');
}
```

Thanks to all who commented nonetheless.